# I need some assistance in certain sections of Naive set theory by Paul R Halmos

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I (16M) was studying the aforementioned books and couldn't grasp certain parts of it . Could someone please explain these parts more explicitly.
here goes-

1. I understood the Axiom of Extension in the first chapter but right after that there is a line
   'A set is determined by its extension'
   In chapter 3 last page Halmos writes  ' A class may be identified with a condition (sentence) or rather with the "extension" of a condition
   What do you precisely mean by extension in set theory (I understood the Russel's Paradox if that helps)
2. Can someone give a precise clear definition of 'order' in a set.
3. 'Suppose for instance that we consider human beings instead of sets and that if x and A are human beings we write x ∈ A if x is an ancestor of A . The analogue of the axiom of extension would say here that if two human beings are equal then they have the same ancestors (this is the "only if" and this is true) and also that is two human beings have the same ancestors then they are equal (this is the "if" part and it is false).
   What do you mean by this para ?
4. Why can't we talk of intersections of non empty collections whereas we can talk of union of empty collections

thanks for your help

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851728/what-does-extension-mean-in-the-axiom-of-extension

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "extension" mean in the Axiom of extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851728/what-does-extension-mean-in-the-axiom-of-extension)

Comment: What do you mean by (16M) ?

Comment: I meant age and gender

Comment: See [Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_set#Informal_definition). The set $\{ a,b,c \}$ has no "order" because - due to Extensionality - it is the same set as $\{ c,b,a \}$

Comment: 3. Two brothers have the same set of *ancestors* (parents, grandparents, etc.) but they are **not** equal (they are two distinct individuals).

Comment: 4. ??? page 15?

Answer (score 1):

The axiom of extension states that if
$X\subset Y$ and $Y\subset X$ then $X=Y$, which is saying that two sets are identical iff their elements are identical.
Regarding classes (which are not sets), I believe that what you've wrote basically means that a class is defined by a condition (any element satisfying such conditions would be in the class) or, equivalently, defined by the 'extension' of that condition, which contains every condition equivalent to the original one. \